# Enable OTG with a shell command

Tags: settings, shell, usb-on-the-go, command-line

I'm running Android Pie on a rooted OnePlus 6, and I wanted to know how I can enable OTG with a shell command. I need this in order to automate some tasks.

There is a setting that can toggle OTG, found in `settings > system > OTG storage`, so I figured something like this would work:

```
settings put global otg_enabled 1
```

However I'm unsure what the setting for OTG is actually called; I tried a bunch of possibilities but none seemed to work. Also tried googling it, but found nothing.

Anyone able to help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: the solution is tested on a rooted OnePlus 6 running OxygenOS (**Android 8, 9, 10**).

---

The command I use is:

```
adb shell su -c 'setprop persist.sys.oem.otg_support true'
```

Some folks on some  forums suggested to toggle the value for the global settings key `oneplus_otg_auto_disable`, but it never worked out for me. My solution survives reboot and OTG would work even when decryption password is not supplied.

I automate the solution for fail-safe scenario (in case something disable the OTG)  using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) app. My task is:

Code → Run Shell:

- `setprop persist.sys.oem.otg_support true`
- enable *Use Root*

I then assign the task to a boot event profile so that the task runs during startup.

Comment: I think both - property and settings key - are OEM specific, not part of AOSP.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I didn't see such keys in my Nexus 6 running Android 7, back when I had it.

Comment: on my rooted OnePlus 10 Pro 5G (NE2213): my problem was that the OTG toggle was greyed out and could not be changed from "off". Attaching a usb flash stick got "recognizing" and nothing more. I used the "setprop" ..true command, and the disk was mounted read/write (both ntfs and ext4 usb disks worked). i then used set property... false, and now i could toggle the otg setting! upon reboot i can now toggle the otg setting.  perhaps "all" i needed was a reboot, but I'll never know. In any case, problem solved for me, thx

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

turn ON:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/power_supply/usb/otg_switch
```

turn OFF:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/power_supply/usb/otg_switch
```

This doesn't change the toggle button's state on OTG setting page though.

Comment: Hi. It would be good if your answer mentions a couple of details, such as: 1) the solution needs root access to work; 2) the solution won't survive a reboot; 3) the Android device and Android version on which this solution was tested.