# Enabling debugging with broken screen and usb keyboard (Google assistant working)

Tags: screen, usb-debugging, external-keyboard, google-assistant, oneplus-5t

Is there a way to enable USB debugging with broken display - black screen and touches are not registering.
Ultimately I want to control my phone (answer phone calls, see messages, restore images, access bank mobile 2fa) through [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy), but it requires USB debugging mode.

Most tutorials make use of USB keyboard/mouse but for some reason they are not functioning (Oneplus 5t), and I have tested adapter+keyboard on different phone and it works.
What I have at my disposal

- Unlockable phone - fingerprint sensor
- Google assistant - it responds to "hey google"
- Phone is connected to Wi-Fi and I can install apps through google play store on my PC

Comment: don't quite understand - otg is working or not? did you provide external power to otg hub? can you access files via MTP after unlocking with fingerprint?

Comment: Without an USB keyboard the chance is next to zero. Make sure to connect a plain USB keyboard, without anything special (no RGB LEDs, a smartcard reader and no integrated USB hub) and attach it directly to the phone (only use a simple USB-C/A adapter).

Comment: From the information I can gather - to be able to use USB OTG devices on Oneplus phones, you need to enable "OTG storage" which I cant do without screen or keyboard.

Comment: @Firelord you have Oneplus device don't you, can you shed some light here maybe?

Comment: @alecxs A problem with OTG on OnePlus devices is that the user has to enable OTG first in the settings app before using it!  One has to go into Settings -> System -> enable OTG storage setting. That setting auto disables after 10 minutes of inactivity! To keep it enabled all the time I use this tweak of mine: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216273/96277

Comment: @Firelord Not quite sure how is this relevant in this case - since I can not enable OTG storage setting with touch controls and because I don't have debugging enabled I also cant set the flag through adb. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Jimbo actually, user alecxs asked me if I could help out with OTG issue on a OnePlus device, so I told him why OTG is not working for OP (you, that is). Given your situation, its relevancy is its explanation as to why your OTG (USB keyboard/mouse) is not working at all in your OP5 device, even though it is fully functional.

Comment: @Jimbo I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution? I can make Google assistant to start Teamviewer or Anydesk apps but they both need confirmation to start remote access which is not possible. 

I can't find any solution.