# I have connected an OTG cable to my OnePlus device, but nothing happens. What to do?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, oxygenos, oneplus

*This is a self-answer post written in response to a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236120/96277) where the user couldn't figure out why their well-functioning OTG device was not working on their OnePlus device*.

So, I have a OnePlus device running stock OxygenOS. I decided to connect an accessory to my device through an OTG cable/adapter but I see that the device doesn't detect or shows any response when I insert it. My cable/adapter works in other devices, so I'm a bit clueless here.

How do I get my OTG cable/adapter working in my OnePlus device?

Answer (score 1):

OnePlus' OxygenOS (the Android OS that came with your OnePlus device or got updated some time ago) keeps OTG setting disabled by-default. A user has to enable that setting before using their OTG device. The setting can be found in **Settings** app **→ System → OTG storage**.

If you cannot find that setting there, search for "OTG" term in Settings app and the relevant setting should show up. Once enabled, plug in your OTG cable/adapter along with your accessory and it should work (provided Android supports it of course!)

Do **note** that the OTG storage **setting would auto-disable after 10 minutes** of OTG inactivity. So you would have to enable the setting again should you find yourself in need of using your OTG accessory.

To keep the setting enabled all the time, see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216273/96277) (required a rooted OxygenOS).